# How to disable the "autodeploy" to server feature in an Eclipse web project

Tags: eclipse, deployment

I am using Eclipse (J2EE Galileo) and have created a dynamic web project and associated it with a server (JBoss).

Now, whenever I make changes to one of my JSP pages, Eclipse will build and autodeploy the WAR file to the server. This is sometimes useful, but sometimes more in the way for me.

I would like to disable this feature, and instead just use the "publish" feature to deploy whenever I want. I still want to run the server from within Eclipse.

But I cannot find a setting for this, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Open the servers view. (Window -> Show view -> Servers)

From the servers view open your server configuration and will show a page with your server name, runtime environment, etc.

In that page there will be a collapsed panel titled 'publishing' that let's you configure when to publish or disable the automatic publishing.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted! 
It never occured to me to double click the server in question, I had only tried the context menus "properties", which were quite unhelpful

Comment: I see no such 'publishing' panel in Rational Application Developer 8.0.3.

Comment: Found this for Rational Application Developer:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21306325

Comment: To "open your server configuration" and show the page with server name etc., you need to DOUBLE CLICK the entry with your server in the "servers" view. Took me a couple of minutes to figure this one out :D

Comment: I found the same option on Window->Preferences->Server->Lanching.
There is a checkbox saying "Automatically publish when starting servers" that needs to be unchecked.

Comment: Is there a way I can turn off Automatic Publishing for 1 project only? I have 2 projects configured to deploy to my server but I only want 1 of them to not be published automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The Rational Application Developer **RAD** (which is based on Eclipse) has this option hidden inside the ‘Server’ View in the upper right corner.

[image: Rational Application Developer]

Comment: This button is also available in plain Eclipse

Answer (score -3):

Under Project -> Build automatically has to be unchecked.

Comment: That might work, but was not what I was after, since I want automatic Build, just not deployment.